# Change border color for TinyMCE table in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, tinymce-4

I have a problem with HTML tables created with a TinyMCE editor. I set the border color for table, th and td in my CSS stylesheet:

```
body table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-color: #eeeeee;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
body table th,
body table td {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

If I set a table border in my TinyMCE editor, the HTML output looks similar to this:

```
<table border="1">
...
</table>
```

The table border is grey in Firefox, but stays black in Internet Explorer no matter what I set in my CSS.

Any hints why this setting is ignored in IE?

Comment: the html/css you have posted is fine and produces border, your settings ,may be overwritten by TinyMCE editor.

Comment: The described output shows the situation on a page where I only display the created output. There is no TinyMCE editor on this page.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
body table {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border:1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that this 1px border is always shown, even if I don't want to have a border or the border should be 2px...

Comment: if u dont want border means give border as 0

Comment: If I set border to 0 in my TinyMCE editor, I would still see a border because of the CSS you wrote...

Comment: in css use border:none;